# How can I Host a worker service on IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-5.0, worker-service

I have a .net core 5 worker service project that is running as windows service. I have also incorporated http polling using kestrel server.
I need to use this as Website(deployed on IIS) instead of Windows service.
Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this because I can't find any helpful material on this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it may difficult even impossible.

Actually, if any application can host or Microsoft suggest users host on IIS, you can see "IIS Express" in VS. However, I cannot see that when create a worker service application.

[image]

Maybe you will find other ways to deploy the worker service, but this is not guaranteed to work perfectly on IIS.You can come with a partial solution this way:

Create a WCF service method that checks if your long-running thread is alive and if not, starts it.
Create a very simple windows service that periodically (once in 5 seconds) calls that method. Deploy the service somewhere, e.g. on your own machine.